# Angular Meteor 1.3 Ionic - how add ngCordova?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, ngcordova

**I would like to add ngCordova in my Angular Meteor 1.3 Ionic Project.**

- I based to the following example but without success (probably cause it's not Meteor 1.3) : https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-ionic-example
- I tested this package https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-ng-cordova but  it doesn't work (probably, its no work with meteor 1.3)

=> I've got this error on google chrome console : 
*partyAdd.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: _angular2.default.module(...).component is not a function*

=> I've got this error on Ios Simulator console (on Safari) : 
*TypeError: _angular2['default'].module(name, [_angularMeteor2['default']]).component is not a function. (In '_angular2['default'].module(name, [_angularMeteor2['default']]).component', '_angular2['default'].module(name, [_angularMeteor2['default']]).component' is undefined)*

**Could you help me please to add ngCordova ?** 
from this tutoriel : http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/ionic

Thank you

Comment: same here.. have solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, see it fits for you:

First install angular-component

- meteor npm install --save angular-component

Then add in your main.js

- import 'angular-component';

Comment: I didn't find that angular-component has anything to do with ng-cordova. Looks like angular-component is just a polyfill for letting you write components in the Angular2 syntax, in an Angular 1 project – maybe if you are running < Angular 1.5. Thus, I think you don't need angular-component either, if you have Angular 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save ng-cordova`

Then, where you define your main app's angular module (in my case at the top of app.js) add:

`import 'ng-cordova'`

Of course, remove any Atmosphere package you might have had for ngCordova if you're upgrading from Meteor 1.2